# Regex to get the word after brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, brackets

I would like to have a Regex select the next word after brackets containing letters. There can be more than multiple brackets following each other before the next word.

Example:

`[X]word[y][Z]another`
Expected output: word, another

I would like also to achieve the same but providing the regex the content between the brackets and get the following word:

Example 2: i would like the next word after [y]:

`[X]word[y][Z]another`
Expected output: another

I tried `(?m)^\[[^\]\[]*\]\K.+` but somehow it's not working.

Comment: Are you working with a programming language here?

Comment: Try `\[[^][]*](*SKIP)(*F)|[^][]+`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript does not support `\K` or inline modifiers like `(?m)`

You might use for example a capture group for 1 or more word characters, and first match from `[...]`

```
\[[^\][]*](\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OmgmLu/1)

Or providing the regex the content between the brackets and capture the following word, by optionally repeating `[...]` after it:

```
\[y](?:\[[^\][]*])*(\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uvs0Oi/1)

Comment: this matches exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
\[y\](?:\[[^\[\]]*\])*([^\[\]]*)
```

will capture the next word after the bracket which contains the specified character (here [y] as an example), excluding all brackets and stuff inside of them.

Example:

[X]word[y][i][ee][Z]another

=> group1 = "another"

[X]word[y][i][ee][Z]another[eer]eeee[ee]

=> group1 = "another"

and so on.

When asking these type of questions, I suggest you put as many examples as you can, it helps a lot with figuring out what you mean

if you want to change the input character, you can change "y" to whichever character you need in the regex. It should be possible to do programatically

Comment: for some reason, this is not working...

Comment: must be because of special characters? If you test it here: https://regex101.com/ it works for the examples I did

Comment: this : `.*\[X\](?:\[[a-zA-Z]*\])*([a-zA-Z-äÄëËöÖüÜ]*)(?:\[.*)` works. 
However, it fails with:  `.*\[Par\](?:\[[a-zA-Z]*\])*([a-zA-Z-äÄëËöÖüÜ]*)(?:\[.*)` expected output: `opa` 
This also fails: `.*\[Af\](?:\[[a-zA-Z]*\])*([a-zA-Z-äÄëËöÖüÜ]*)(?:\[.*)` 
Expected output: `ita, sta`
See here for details: https://regex101.com/r/wFch0k/1

Comment: I fixed it, but someone already posted a better version I guess ^^ It's a learning experience for me, I underuse \w+ for words and tent to try to match the whole line when it's not necessary

Comment: it also takes into account your new character, the use of [^\\[\\]] accepts all characters except brackets so this is more reliable than \w or even [a-zA-Z-äÄëËöÖüÜ]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one regex approach.  We can eagerly try to match a term in `[...]`, and that failing, match a single word.  Then, we can filter off the terms matched in square brackets, leaving behind the words we want to match.

```js
var input = "[X]word[y][Z]another";
var matches = input.match(/\[.*?\]|\w+/g)
                   .filter(x => !x.match(/^\[.*\]$/));
console.log(matches);
```